Cleaning up dried PVC Cement Drip
A previous homeowner or plumber used too much PVC cement and there is a pretty long "drip" trail that has run down the outside of the CPVC pipe and fully hardened. For an upcoming repair, I'd like to cut this pipe (cutting through the "drip"), clean it up, and ultimately join with a coupler.
I've only ever started with fresh clean CPVC pipes, so I'm unsure: Can I just sand away the dried CPVC, or will this create some kind of bonding issue when I apply the primer and new cement?

You can surely sand away the drip.
Sometimes it is easier to cut away the bulk of it with a razor knife or single edge blade then sand.
Apply primer and glue to both the pipe and fitting and hold in place for 20 seconds or so and you will be fine.

yes, it's perfectly valid to sand, file, or scrape the drip off.

Just as long as you don't go crazy and sand away half the pipe thickness!
